# Could anyone show me how to approach this problem ? I am learning it on my on and have found it on the web.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am learning it on my on and have found this on the web. I would appreciate a long and comprehensive explanation.
So my problem is, I don’t know where to start. I don’t unterstand the first expression. Maybe it is the same as supx supy... the second example o thought of fixing one variable, taking the biggest number 1 and taking the sup regarding the other variable, which would equal to 5?! These are my thoughts. I simply need an example in wich I can see, how to deal with it and how to interpret it correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to edit this before it is closed.  Issues include (a) an uninformative title, (b) a question which is in fact a picture, and (c) no indication of your thoughts so far and where you are stuck

Comment: Now, I did. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\sup_{x\in X;\,y\in Y}f(x,y)$ is $\sup \{f(x,y): x\in X\land y\in Y\},$ which is $\sup \{3x+2y:0\le x\le 1\land 0\le y\le 1\},$ which is $\sup [0,5]$ which is $5.$

A $\sup$ or $\inf$ is the l.u.b. or g.l.b. of a $set$ of numbers. So first define or describe the $set$.

$$\inf_{y\in Y}\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y)=\inf_{y\in Y}(\,\sup_{x\in X} f(x,y)\,)=$$ $$=\inf  \{\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y): y\in Y\}=$$ $$=\inf \{\sup \{f(x,y):x\in X\}:y\in Y\}=$$ $$=\inf \{\sup \{3x+2y: 0\le x\le 1\}: 0\le y\le 1\}=$$ $$=\inf \{\sup [2y,3+2y]: 0\le y\le 1\}=$$ $$=\inf \{3+2y:0\le y\le 1\}=$$ $$=\inf [3,5]=3.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I do have a detailed and formal way how to do it. It seems pretty complicated but once you break it down to the fundamentals it becomes much easier. @DanielWainfleet

Comment: one final question. When calculating the sup (so the inner part) how do I treat y? At that point i don’t care what y is right ? I simply take the sup in respect to x regardless of what y is. If y would be Element of [-1,0] would that change the sup ? So I’m asking for dependencies or in dependencies.

Comment: For $each$ $y,$ we examine the set $\{3x+2y: x\in [0,1]\},$ which is the set $[2y,3+2y],$ & its $\sup$ is $3+2y.$

Comment: Did you see that the first 3 values in your Q are equal, regardless of what $f,X,Y$ are?

Comment: I don’t get your point. So does y matter for the supremum or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll do the fourth one as an example, I’ll leave it up to you to do the rest, as these are similar problem.

So we’re interested in $\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}\,\inf_{0 \leq y \leq 1}\,f(x,y)$.

Let $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Then $g_x:\,y \in Y \longmapsto f(x,y)$ is $y \in [0,1] \longmapsto 3x+2y$. This function is increasing (indeed, for any $0 \leq x,y,y’ \leq 1$, if $y < y’$ then $3x+2y < 3x+2y’$).

Therefore, $\inf_{0 \leq y \leq 1}\,f(x,y)=g_x(0)=3x$ for any $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

So the quantity we are interested in is $\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}\,3x$. As $x \in [0,1] \longmapsto 3x$ is increasing again, this supremum is $3*1=3$.

Comment: Thank you so my thought was correct. Could you just tell me what they mean by the first impression?

Comment: What do you mean, the first impression?

Comment: The first task/exercise

Comment: Just notice that for all $x,y$ in their domains, $f(x,y) \leq f(1,1)=5$ (and $(1,1)$ is in the domain, so $5$ is the maximum).

Comment: So it is the same as sup x sup y f(x,y) right ?

Comment: Actually, yes. But not according to the exact definition.

Comment: I thought of it analogous to the(double) sum. But thanks.